# How can I create a javascript to show and hide info according option value selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a combobox to show moths, when I do click on january I only need to see div1 and febraury need to see div 2 like this:

```
   January........
   <div> It will show info when only january  is selected</div>

   Febraury........
   <div> It will show info when only febraury is selected</div>
```

Here is my information:

```
 <select id="month" name="month">
   <option value="1">January</option>
   <option value="2">Febraury</option>
   <option value="3">March</option>
 </select>


 <-------ALL MY DIVS WILL BE HIDE  -------------->
  <div> It will show info when only january  is selected</div>
  <div> It will show info when only Febraury is selected</div>
  <div> It will show info when only March    is selected</div>
 <----- It should show each div according option div is selected ----->
```

Here is my demo

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/q2E5e/
```

Please somebody can help me with this?

I will really appreciate help

Comment: Well what have you tried? that jsfiddle only includes html. SO isn't about writing your code for you, it's more about helping you fix your own

Comment: @yuvi sorry i pasted bad the link, can you check again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HQu64/3/)

You need to give id to your div, then use:

```
divJan.style.display = "block";
```

block will show your div, none will hide it.
You just need a function that will determine wich element is selected and an event to track the changes. Here's an example:

```
var cmbMonth = document.getElementById('month');
var divJan = document.getElementById('divJan');
var divFeb = document.getElementById('divFeb');
var divCoo = document.getElementById('divCoo');

cmbMonth.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

    if (cmbMonth.value == 1) {
        divJan.style.display = "block";
        divFeb.style.display = "none";
        divCoo.style.display = "none";

    } else if (cmbMonth.value == 2) {
        divJan.style.display = "none";
        divFeb.style.display = "block";
        divCoo.style.display = "none";

    } else if (cmbMonth.value == 3) {
        divJan.style.display = "none";
        divFeb.style.display = "none";
        divCoo.style.display = "block";
    }

});
```

Comment: shryme thanks your code seems working but how can i do to not show all divs until i do click on the month?

Comment: Then simply use `style="display:none"` in your div, see my updated fiddle in my post for an example. (or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HQu64/3/))

Answer (score 2):

A jQuery solution using

```
$('#month').change()
```

and

```
$(some id).hide()
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPXFV/)

Answer (score 1):

At first, instead of hidden div elements with text, would be better if you create an array with text values, that should be shown after selecting appropriate values.

```
var divTextValues = [
    "You selected January",
    "You selected February",
    "You selected March",
];
```

Second, for simplicity start values of dropdown list from 0.

```
<select id="month" name="month">
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
</select>
```

Third, hide div element by default.

```
<div id="displayMonth" style="display:none;"></div>
```

And then add event handler.

```
var month = document.getElementById("month"),
    displayMonth = document.getElementById("displayMonth");

month.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    var selected = this[this.selectedIndex];
    if (selected.value > -1) {
        displayMonth.textContent = divTextValues[selected.value];
        displayMonth.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        displayMonth.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

[***Demonstration***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/6bQSz/2/)